# max value of a column

Tags: sql, max

I am new in this forum and need some help!

My code is not giving the correct result. The problem is that I am not getting the max value of t140.BEL_GRLAG_AP (that is what I try to do in line num. 16). The sql still gives two or more lines per person and I only want one line per person, the one with max(t140.BEL_GRLAG_AP).

Can any of you tell me what I am missing ?
Any help is apprecieted!

```
select distinc tort128.NUM_AVTALE_ID as AvtaleID
, tort009.IDE_ARBGIV_NR as Orgnr
, tort134.NVN_ARBGIV as Arbeidsgiver
, mid(convert(varchar(8),tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM),7,2) + 
mid(convert(varchar(8),tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM),5,2) +
mid(convert(varchar(8),tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM),1,4) + 
RIGHT('00000' + TRIM(convert(CHAR(5),tort127.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR)),5) as Fødselsnummer
, tort001.NVN_KUNDE_FOR + ' ' + tort001.NVN_KUNDE_ETTER as Navn
, tort140.NUM_ALDERSGRENSE as Aldersgrense

from tort128

join tort127 on tort128.IDE_SEKV_TORT127 = tort127.IDE_SEKV_TORT127
join tort001 on tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM = tort001.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM and  tort127.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR=tort001.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR
join tort009 on tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM = tort009.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM and   tort127.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR=tort009.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR
join tort134 on tort009.IDE_ARBGIV_NR = tort134.IDE_ARBGIV_NR
join tort138 on tort128.IDE_SEKV_TORT128 = tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT128
left join tort140 on tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT138 = tort140.IDE_SEKV_TORT138 
and tort140.BEL_GRLAG_AP=(select max(t140.BEL_GRLAG_AP) from tort140 t140
where 1 = 1
  and t140.IDE_SEKV_TORT138 = tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT138)
and tort140.BEL_LOENN_AAR = (select max(t140_2.BEL_LOENN_AAR) from tort140 t140_2
where 1 = 1
  and t140_2.IDE_SEKV_TORT138 = tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT138)

where

tort128.NUM_AVTALE_ID = 200854
and tort128.DAT_GYLDIG_FOM <= 20120101
and (tort128.DAT_GYLDIG_TOM >= 20120101
or tort128.DAT_GYLDIG_TOM is null)
and tort128.DAT_HISTORISK is null
and tort128.TYP_STATUS! = 'kns'
and tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM >= 19460101
and tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM <= 19551234
and tort127.DAT_TERMINERT is null
and tort127.DAT_REGISTRERT <= 20120101
and tort009.DAT_SLUTT is null
and tort134.DAT_HISTORISK is null
and tort138.DAT_AKSJON=(select max(p.DAT_AKSJON) from tort138 p
where 1 = 1
and p.IDE_SEKV_TORT128=tort128.IDE_SEKV_TORT128)

order by

tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM
```

Comment: You should always include code, even if you haven't learned how to use SO's tools to format it: someone will come along and help with that. Include your code, and your desired output along with a sample of what your current code is outputting.

Comment: Post your code by adding four spaces before it or wrap it in tildas (`) if you want it to be inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are joining on different tables then you can do something like the following:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.id, t2.val
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Max(value) val, id
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Would you suggest that I should re-structured my code as you suggests? how would you do it if you join 3 tables for example? NB! I managed to post my actual code.

Comment: I figured out how to join multiple tables and select max(value) of some of them. One question, Do u know if that syntax is compatible with access?

Comment: @user1571823 MS Access does allow `MAX()` but you will need to test it to verify it works.  Access is different in its syntax

Comment: One more question..... Lets say that I do the above procedure with 4 tables insted of 2, and I want to chose the max value of one column in the third table. How should i wrtite that? Sorry guys but I am new here.... how can I replay having the chance to paste a code?

Comment: @user1571823 you would use `JOIN`s on all of the tables but you would use a subquery on the third table that you want the `MAX()` value on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `GROUP BY`.

For example, if you have three columns: `Value, ID, Tag` and want to get the max `Value` for each `ID/Tag` combination, you would do

```
SELECT MAX(Value), ID, Tag
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, Tag
```

Comment: I am joining different tables not just one

Comment: You can still do something like this:

`SELECT MAX(A.Value), A.ID, B.Tag
FROM
  ATable A
  JOIN
  BTable B
  ON
    ...
GROUP BY A.ID, B.Tag`